# Why is SystemProperty.environment.value() returning null in Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, junit

I have a Google App Engine Java app that is returning null from SystemProperty.environment.value(), and all other static members of SystemProperty.  I see this when running my JUnit tests via Maven.

```
import com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty;
...
void printProps() {
    log.info("props:" + System.getProperties());
    log.info("env=" + SystemProperty.environment.value());
    log.info("log=" + System.getProperty("java.util.logging.config.file"));
    log.info("id=" + SystemProperty.applicationId.get());
    log.info("ver=" + SystemProperty.applicationVersion.get());
}
```

The only item above that returns non-null is System.getProperties().

Here are some of the details of my setup:

- IntelliJ IDEA EAP 13
- Maven
- App Engine SDK 1.8.5
- Java 7 (1.7.0_40)
- JUnit 4

Comment: I can provide more details of my setup and code as needed, but I'm unsure of what more to post at this point.  I guess I'm looking for advice on what to check.

Comment: After deploying this on the devserver and into production, I'm finding that the environment is there and is just fine.  I guess for my JUnit tests I'm responsible for providing the environment myself.  I'll go re-read the docs for JUnit with App Engine to see exactly what I need to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having the same problem. I attempted to call these methods on LocalServiceTestHelper, but these did NOT populate SystemProperty.applicationId or SystemProperty.version

```
setEnvAppId(java.lang.String envAppId) 
setEnvVersionId(java.lang.String envVersionId)
```

e.g.

```
public final LocalServiceTestHelper helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig(), new LocalTaskQueueTestConfig() ).setEnvAppId("JUnitApplicationId").setEnvVersionId("JUnitVersion");
```

My solution was simply to populate those properties myself in my JUnit setUp() method:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    SystemProperty.version.set("JUnitVersion");
    SystemProperty.applicationId.set("JUnitApplicationId");
    SystemProperty.applicationVersion.set("JUnitApplicationVersion");
    SystemProperty.environment.set( SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Development );
    helper.setUp();
    datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();
}
```

Note that the only valid values for SystemProperty.Environment are the static final values Production and Development.